# PostgreSQL time conversion/formatting from "24:00:00" to "00:00:00" in SELECT statement

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, scientific-computing

I have some market data with time fields stored in a PostgreSQL database. PostgreSQL uses the format "00:00:00" to "24:00:00" to store times (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) which works perfectly as long as I only work within the database.

The problem is that I have to do some data processing (using Python) afterwards and the Python *datetime.time* format only supports the hours from "00:00:00" to "23:00:00". So if I fetch a record that contains "24:00:00" using the *psycopg2* module I get an error **"ValueError: hour must be in 0..23"** because the time field cannot be converted properly.

My idea for a clean workaround is to convert the time field that contains the "24:00:00" hour already in the SELECT statement to "00:00:00". This would solve the problem as the converter function would not fail afterwards.

I have already looked at the formatting functions (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) but could not find anything suitable..

Is there a way to realize this using SQL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My actual workaround ist to use function "to_char(time_field, 'HH24:MI:SS')" which converts the field into a character. But this only allows me to display the data. If I want to use time functions I need it in the Python *datetime.time* format.

Comment: Do you mean a SQL query to convert the date from 24:00:00 to 00:00:00 in PostgresSQL?

Comment: Can you show us an example of your query and the definition of the table? I ask this because psycopg2 should be able to round trip `datetime.time` (Python) and `timestamp` (PostgreSQL) values without any error.

Comment: That is odd. My first guess is that `24:00:00` represents the leap seconds http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second (which is very rare, and usually displayed as `23:59:60`) -- it seems PostgreSQL only support leap second, if the underlying operating system supports it http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#AEN14725 (f.ex. SQLFiddle's PostgreSQL does not support it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/02129/1 )

Comment: Don't worry, this is a psycopg2 error. I'll report it. In the meantime see my answer for a workaorund.

Comment: One possible workaround is to convert it to `timestamp` (adding `current_date`) & convert it back to `time`, f.ex. `(current_date + time_col)::time` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/02129/3

Comment: @ fog: Here's the table definition `CREATE TABLE public.de_tr_pos_price
(
  date date,
  product_name character(10),
  start_time time without time zone,
  end_time time without time zone,
  capacity_price numeric,
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('de_tr_neg_price_id_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT de_tr_neg_price_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)`

and my query (shortened):

`SELECT
  id,
  date,
  product_name,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  capacity_price
FROM de_tr_pos_price;`

Thanks for your workaround and also for the other answers. They both do their job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `time` to a `date` the result is a `timestamp` which you can cast to `time`:

```
select (current_date + market_data_time)::time;
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the value `'24:00:00'::time` is clearly a psycopg2 error. While we wait for Daniele or me to fix it (if possible at all), here's a workaround: just use a `CASE` expression to check for the specific value that cause the error. If your table is named `tab` and the `time` column is `t` then you can do:

```
SELECT CASE t WHEN '24:00:00'::time THEN '0:00:00'::time ELSE t END FROM tab;
```

And everything should work.

Note that this is a problem only if you extract a `time` column. It seems that PostgreSQL converts `timestamp` columns (even ones representing a leap second) to the corresponding midnight, i.e., `2012-6-30T24:00:00` (30 June 2012 leap second) results in `2012-7-1T00:00:00`.